# Need help with a DC-DC converter using a MC34063

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to make a DC/DC converter from 12V to 5V using a [MC34063](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF).  I found an old cell phone car charger and removed everything and set it up on my breadboard.  I'm getting 5V out but only  0.12A.  I checked the car charger before I took it out and it was 5V and 1.0A.  I set it up exactly as in this image:

[image]

I'm not sure where I could have messed it up.

Comment: What is your load? Less than 5 ohms?

Comment: The schematic dictates max 500mA, not 1A.

Comment: Vin on the schematic says 25V while your post says 12V. Also, where are you getting your 12V from and is it current-limited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF it worked before then your loop area is too big in your layout. Keep all wires short as possible in the loop.

Consolidate all your Grounds, Vin ,L ,Co, Zener, Rsc, wires to pin 1,2,7,8, and caps connected to IC within a 1" radius. Even if running 20~50KHz the dV/Dt is high and is affected by stray capacitance.

Then double Ct form 470 pf to 1000 and Freq will go down almost 50% current in the inductor will rise and may saturate L.

Otherwise calculate from table and make sure L is rated for 2x 1Amp.
[image]

Consider a preload of 10% on output for stability open loop testing.
Check Q1 to see if it gets hot.

Got a scope? check pins 2,3 & 5.

Answer (score 2):

The capacitor *C<sub>T</sub>* changes the duty cycle. Parasitic capacitance from the breadboard will increase its value. Play with this capacitor after studying p.4 of [the datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF).

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I recon the 0.33 ohm resistor you are using is actually a 3.3 ohm resistor (3rd band gold, should be silver)
Colour code for a 0.33 ohm R should be orange, orange, silver, plus tolerance band gold 5% brown 1% red 2%

Comment: While this may be correct, as is this is too short of an answer. If you added why a 3.3 ohm resistor would result in 0.12 Amps out that would be better.